# How to open two JFrame at the same time?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two objects JFrame and when I invoke them since the same class, first one is opened and when it finishes its execution, it starts the other one.
It's the first time that I work JFrame.

Comment: please spend some time to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide your code. Will help others solve your problem.

Comment: Providing your code will help best to provide some help. I have a first guess though: if you need two JFrames to work in paralell, you might have to interact with them from different Threads. However, as said before, providing your code is the best start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, as mentioned by martin.

```
/**
 * @author iGeeks
 * @date   2015-01-08
 */

package ly.gress.frames;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestTwoFrames implements Runnable{

    JFrame theFrame;


    public TestTwoFrames(JFrame f) {
        this.theFrame = f;
    }


    // Run two Frames in separate therads
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame("f1 title");
        JFrame f2 = new JFrame("f2 title");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new TestTwoFrames(f1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new TestTwoFrames(f2));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        theFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        theFrame.setVisible(true);

        // Attention: This closes the app, and therefore both frames!
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

} // end class TestTwoFrames
```